# Xamarin.forms list of list for carousal view

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin.forms app which uses a carousal view.My carousal view have 6 items per view. But now it shows one item per view. I know the problem is I need to create a ***List of List***.But I am stuck at this.

**My expected output of carousal view is like this.**

[image]
[image]

**But what I am getting now is like this**

[image]
[image]

My orginal list that contains data is like this.

```
 ObservableCollection<SECHomescreenData> resultObjForSEC = callForSECtilesScreen.APICallResult<ObservableCollection<SECHomescreenData>>();
```

my SECHomescreenData.

```
  public partial class SECHomescreenData
   {        
       public string Status { get; set; }    
       public string Countered { get; set; }
   }
```

When I bind this list to my carousal view,It will only shows one item per view.What I am trying to achieve is fill the data into 6 items of carousal and if there is 7 th item , go to the next page of carousal view. So how can I achieve this? If it requires list of list, how can I do it? Any help is appreciated.

**My XAML.**

```
  <controls:CarouselViewControl IndicatorsTintColor="LightBlue"  ArrowsTintColor="White"   CurrentPageIndicatorTintColor="White"  ItemsSource="{Binding SECList}" ShowIndicators="True" AnimateTransition="True" ShowArrows="True"  Orientation="Horizontal"  InterPageSpacing="10"   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
            <controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
         <Grid RowSpacing="5" ColumnSpacing="5" >                   
            <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsClippedToBounds="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#4D2F4F4F" BorderColor="#294145"
                    >                       
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>  
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid RowSpacing="3">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,10,2" HeightRequest="1" Color="LightGreen"></BoxView>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Category}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Small" TextColor="LightGray" Margin="2,0,0,0" >                                      
                            </Label>
                            <Label Text="153" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,0,0,0" >                                      
                            </Label>
                            <Image Source="alllead.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#4D2F4F4F" BorderColor="#294145" >
                <Grid RowSpacing="3">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,10,2" HeightRequest="1" Color="LightPink"></BoxView>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Category}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Small" TextColor="LightGray" Margin="2,0,0,0" >                              
                    </Label>
                    <Label Text="123" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,0,0,0">                             
                    </Label>
                    <Image Source="openlead.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Image>
                </Grid>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsClippedToBounds="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#4D2F4F4F" BorderColor="#294145" >           
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid RowSpacing="3">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,10,2" HeightRequest="1" Color="LightSalmon"></BoxView>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Category}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Small" TextColor="LightGray" Margin="2,0,0,0" >                                     
                            </Label>
                            <Label Text="153" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,0,0,0">                                     
                            </Label>
                            <Image Source="closedlead.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsClippedToBounds="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#4D2F4F4F" BorderColor="#294145" >                    
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid RowSpacing="3">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,10,2" HeightRequest="1" Color="LightGoldenrodYellow"></BoxView>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Category}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Small" TextColor="LightGray" Margin="2,0,0,0" >                                   
                            </Label>
                            <Label Text="18" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,0,0,0">                                    
                            </Label>
                            <Image Source="callback.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsClippedToBounds="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#4D2F4F4F" BorderColor="#294145" >                     
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid RowSpacing="3">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,10,2" HeightRequest="1" Color="LightSeaGreen"></BoxView>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Category}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Small" TextColor="LightGray" Margin="2,0,0,0" >                                      
                            </Label>
                            <Label Text="169" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,0,0,0">                                     
                            </Label>
                            <Image Source="referredby.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>                     
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsClippedToBounds="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="#4D2F4F4F" BorderColor="#294145" >                   
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid RowSpacing="3">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,10,2" HeightRequest="1" Color="LightCyan"></BoxView>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Category}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Small" TextColor="LightGray" Margin="2,0,0,0" >                                       
                            </Label>
                            <Label Text="142" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,0,0,0">                                      
                            </Label>
                            <Image Source="appoinments.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>                     
            </Frame>
         </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:CarouselViewControl>
```

PS: I asked this question before. But there are some changes.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, can you visually show me what do you want?

Comment: @G.hakim ok bro...

Comment: @G.hakim bro.Please check my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually , you don'r need to use **List of List** . Set the size of  each Frame(width equals 1/2 of screen width and height equals 1/3 height of screen) . And set the prpoerty
`Span="3"`

`CarouselView` is released after Xamarin.Forms 4.0 .

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="contentPage"   // set the name of the contentpage
             x:Class="xxx.MainPage">
```

```
<CarouselView  ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout SnapPointsAlignment="Center"  SnapPointsType="Mandatory" Span="3" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentPage}, Path=BindingContext.FrameWidth}" HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference contentPage}, Path=BindingContext.FrameHeight}" HasShadow="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsClippedToBounds="True"  BackgroundColor="#4D2F4F4F" BorderColor="#294145">

                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,10,2" HeightRequest="1" Color="LightGreen"></BoxView>
                            <Label Text="111111" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Small" TextColor="LightGray" Margin="2,0,0,0" >
                            </Label>
                            <Label Text="153" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Medium" Grid.Row="2" Margin="2,0,0,0" >
                            </Label>
                            <Image Source="alllead.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HeightRequest="30" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

#### in Share Project App.xaml.cs

```
public static double ScreenWidth;
public static double ScreenHeight;
```

#### in Android MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
   ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

   base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            
   Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");
   global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

   App.ScreenWidth = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density; 
   App.ScreenHeight =Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels/Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density; 

   LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

#### in iOS

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    //...
    App.ScreenWidth = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
    App.ScreenHeight = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
    //...
}
```

#### in Code Behind or ViewModel

```
public double FrameHeight { get; private set; }
public double FrameWidth { get; private set; }

//...

FrameHeight = App.ScreenHeight/3.0;
FrameWidth = App.ScreenWidth/2.0;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. My problem not with the width or height.. It is about how to set the data as shown in picture

Comment: You can try my solution. It will show 6 items on your screen.

Comment: But what about 7 th item? Will it show on second page of carousal?

Comment: Yes,you can try it first.

Comment: Set the width and height of frame as you want .

Comment: Hi bro I got an error "System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Xamarin.Forms.ItemsView' threw an exception.

Comment: Add  `Forms.SetFlags("CollectionView_Experimental");` to your AppDelegate class on iOS, or to your MainActivity class on Android, before calling Forms.Init:

Comment: Bro, That problem solved . But can I set itemsource like this carousalview.ItemsSource = SECListObj; ?

Comment: Make sure the type of ItemsSource is `ObservableCollection` or `List`.

Comment: Thanks .It will help more people.

Comment: Hi bro I need one help. How to bind the height and width of frame ?